# Set y axis max value with Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I'm trying to draw plots with Matlab and the problem is that i want to fix the maximum value of y-axis to 8 . To help you understand me, look at this first example :

[image: image1]

you can see that the maximum y value is 8. but when i try to draw this graph : 
[image: image2]

its maximum y value is 6 . i want to fix it for all examples to 8.
how can i do it? 
here's my code for now :

```
data=importdata('C:/Users/Eden/Desktop/Calcul_accel/fichier_final.txt');
fig = figure(1);
x=data(:,2)
y=data(:,3)
p=plot(x,y)
set(p,'Color','red');
xlabel('Time(milliseconds)','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color','b');
ylabel('Acceleration(g unit)','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color','b')
```

thank you very much

Comment: You can set the axes of a plot using `axis([x_min x_max y_min y_max])`.

Comment: it worked for me by using "ylim" , thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) if you just want to modify the `y` axis.

Therefore, do this once your plot is already open:

```
ylim([0 8]);
```

This overrides the auto-scaling of the axes so that `y` always spans between 0 to 8.

In general, @eigenchris mentioned to use [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html), which allows you to change the dynamic range of what is viewable in a plot for both the `x` and `y` axes.  However, since you only want to change how the `y`-axis is visualized, one call to `ylim` is enough.